# KeyDown event not Working on PrintScreen Key

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keydown

I am using C# windows Application

I am checking which key, user have pressed down by keyboard.
I have checked for all keys but its not working in case of printScreen

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
}
```

So how to detect <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> Key

Comment: Is it mandatory to detect printscreen with keydown? it is captured by keyup!

Comment: @HPT: You're right, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: The thing is I have the same issue, and I am using the KeyUp event. When I make a new Silverlight app, I can catch the print screen key. But in my old Silverlight app that has some Telerik components in it, this is not working any clue why this is so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use KeyUp, It captures <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key.

Comment: what if i want to detect printscreen on keyDown ?

Answer (score 7):

The print-screen key is trapped by the OS before it is sent to applications. To detect such keys, you need to use a [keyboard hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You may be interested in this article: [Low-level Windows API hooks from C# to stop unwanted keystrokes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/CSLLKeyboard.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
e.Key == Key.Snapshot
```

This will work on KeyUp event

Comment: i asked this ques when i use .net 2.0 framework and i guess this wouldn't work there

Comment: @CainKellye Yes with .net framework 3.5 and above it does not work, you have to use KeyUp event only.

Answer (score 0):

If the `KeyUp` event still does not work try modifying the forms `KeyPreview` property to `true`, then test the the KeyUp event again.