# Set keyboard hook to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, hook

Every windows hook is set to a particular window, or is global. And if I'm not wrong, even the textbox is a window. So, is it possible to set a low level keyboard hook to a specific textbox?

My goal is to capture keydown event on my textbox, but I figured out that using basic method I'm not able to capture the PrintScreen key, so I'm trying to do it another way.

Thanks

Comment: And what if I use WinForms?

Comment: are you talking about a compiled program or in your own application code?

Comment: Almost, but not quite, a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292925/keydown-event-not-working-on-printscreen-key

Comment: @Thorarins It is my own application with my own code.

Comment: @goobering I've already read that question and answer. I need to capture the key on KeyDown event.

Comment: A keyboard hook is not associated with a particular window handle. The keyboard hook event fires prior to routing of the pressed key data to the control that currently has focus.

Comment: So I shall set that hook to parent window and in the event handler check if my textbox is currently focused?

Comment: There is no problem to [use hook in wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1639331/1997232). What you doing in hook function is up to you of course. My previous comments (deleted) are invalid, because keyboard hook doesn't need window handle (thanks @500-InternalServerError for pointing that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrintScreen is a key that triggers a system function, e.g. Copy screen to clipboard.  The key needs to work no matter what UI control has the keyboard focus and is getting the rest of the keystrokes, e.g. your text box. The way to capture this key is with a keyboard hook. See [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94b1598f-79ce-4c70-8851-86aff6d9b12f/capturing-the-print-screen-key?forum=Vsexpressvcs). I believe the code works in both Winforms and WPF.